# Angular2 global variable observable

Tags: angular, observable

I'm fairly new to angular2 and I'm kinda stuck on something.

I've created a global settings.service. This service fetches settings from an API and populate the settings model with the collected data.

The service:

```
public settings : settingsModel;

constructor(public http: Http){ 
     this.setSettings()
         .subscribe(
             (data) => {
                  this.settings = data
             });
  }

setSettings() : Observable<any>{
   return : this.http.get('/settings')
            .map(response =>  response.json());
}

getSettings(){
     return this.settings;
}
```

This works fine and the settings are correctly set when I test the return data in the .map

But when I try to call GetSettings from the component where I need this data, it returns empty. The service is defined in the bootstrap.

Do I need to make the 'settings' variable observable? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Tnx!

Comment: Seems your actual code is different. `correctly set when I test the return data in the .map`. This code `this.http.get('/settings')
            .map(response => {
                this.settings = response.json()
            });` never gets executed without `subscribe(...)`

Comment: Yes, my actual code is different ;) But for the sake of the question I simplified the code. I'll update the code example ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement caching into your service using the `do` operator:

```
private settings : settingsModel;

constructor(public http: Http){ 
  this.settingsObservable = this.http.get('/settings')
        .map(response => response.json())
        .do(settings => {
          this.settings = settings;
        }).share();
}

getSettings() {
  if (this.settings) {
    return Observable.of(this.settings);
  } else {
    return this.settingsObservable;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use a BehaviorSubject, you won't have to `share()` or cache.  See my answer if interested.

Answer (score 8):

Use a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) in your service.  It is already shared, and it will give new subscribers the current value (so it does the caching for you):

```ts
import {Injectable}      from '@angular/core';
import {Http}            from '@angular/http';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {settingsModel}   from 'settingsModel';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private _settingsSource = new BehaviorSubject<settingsModel>(null);
  settings$ = this._settingsSource.asObservable();
  constructor(private _http:Http) {
    this._http.get('./settings.json')
      .subscribe(response => {
        //console.log('response', response)
        this._settingsSource.next(response.json())
      });
  }
}
```

Then use the observable in your template with the asyncPipe, or extract the data into a component variable:

```ts
this.settings$ = this._myService.settings$;  // use with asyncPipe
this._myService.settings$.subscribe(data => this.settings = data);
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3n6fS7MnPpHLdftphkkd?p=preview)</kbd>

In the Plunker I have a child component that waits 4 seconds and then `subscribe()`s, to show that the latest/current value is indeed retrieved.  The Plunker also demonstrates use of the asyncPipe.

Comment: While I like the idea of using a BehaviorSubject for global data, I have difficulties dealing with its initial value which is emitted before any real data has been fetched. In my case I need to get additional data in a component based on the value of the BehaviorSubject, which fails if it contains a null value. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Solved my problem. For anyone looking for a solution, you can use a ReplaySubject instead of a BehaviorSubject to get a Subject that emits changes without having an initial value. The ReplaySubject won't emit any data until next() is called for the first time.

Comment: @Mark Rajcok  - why do you wait 4 seconds? How to wait for his initial value?

Comment: @Tudor-RaduBarbu, I wait 4 seconds just to show how any component that subscribes later will get the latest/current value of the observable.

Comment: @MarkRajcok, thanks mate but can you please tell me. How to nullify/reset the object "this.settings$" after completing an operation.

Comment: Wow, this is the best solution. I never thought that's how BehaviorSubject works. Amazing! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

why not you use your service like this :-

```
  public settings : settingsModel;

constructor(public http: Http){ }

GetSettings(){
  return this.http.get('/settings')
     .map(response => {
           this.settings = response.json()   // here setting your data to `this.setting` 
           return this.settings;
      })
      .catch(err => {
           console.log(err)  // handle your error as you want to handle
      })
}
```

and than use `.subscribe()` method where you want to get the data and show on the view

Comment: I had it like that, but I'm trying to reduce the amount of API calls. Since the data never changes, or is only changed by the client itself it doesn't need to call for 'new' data everytime.

Comment: okay than you can use as @thierry suggested in his answer by using `observable`